# Tensorflow: Make variable trainable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to optimize a variable (parameter of negative binomial distribution), pre-initialized with some Maximum-of-Moments estimator:

```py
sample_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
(r, p) = fit_mme(sample_data) # pre-calculation

# The important part: make `r` trainable
r = tf.Variable(r, dtype=tf.float32, name="r")



#####################################################
# to clarify: from here training of `r`

mu = tf.reduce_mean(sample_data, axis=0, name="mu")
p = mu / (r + mu)
p = tf.identity(p, "p")

distribution = tf.contrib.distributions.NegativeBinomial(total_count=r,
                                    probs=p,
                                    name="nb-dist")
probs = distribution.log_prob(sample_data)
# minimize negative log probability
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(probs, name="loss")

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05)
train_op = train_op.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

errors = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(10000):
        (probs_res, loss_res, _) = \
            sess.run((probs, loss, train_op), feed_dict={sample_data: x})
        errors.append(loss_res)
        print(i)

    r_estim = probs_res.total_count
```

fit_mme:

```
def fit_mme(sample_data, replace_values=None, name=None):
"""
    Calculates the Maximum-of-Momentum Estimator of `NB(r, p)` for given sample data along axis 0.

    :param sample_data: matrix containing samples for each distribution on axis 0\n
        E.g. `(N, M)` matrix with `M` distributions containing `N` observed values each
    :param replace_values: Matrix of size `shape(sample_data)[1:]`
    :param name: A name for the operation (optional).
    :return: estimated values of `r` and `p`
    """
    with tf.name_scope(name, "MME"):
        mean = tf.reduce_mean(sample_data, axis=0, name="mean")
        variance = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(sample_data - mean),
                              axis=0,
                              name="variance")
        if replace_values is None:
            replace_values = tf.fill(tf.shape(variance), math.nan, name="NaN_constant")

        r_by_mean = tf.where(tf.less(mean, variance),
                         mean / (variance - mean),
                         replace_values)
        r = r_by_mean * mean
        r = tf.identity(r, "r")

        p = 1 / (r_by_mean + 1)
        p = tf.identity(p, "p")

        return r, p
```

However, I get the following error:

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified:
>   Tensor("MME/r:0", dtype=float32)

**Is there a better / more clean solution for making `r` trainable?**

Comment: your code isn't clear. I can't understand what you try to achieve

Comment: I've added a whole code example. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Check the shape of `r`.  It should be well defined.

I suspect you have a */None/? for the first dimension to allow you to use different sized batches.

Either fix the shape with `tf.reshape` or collapse the first dimension with  `tf.reduce_mean` or something similar.

Comment: My problem is that `sample_data` is a `tf.placeholder()`.

Comment: If you print `tf.shape(r)` what do you get?

Comment: <tf.Tensor 'Shape_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>

Comment: `shape=(?,)` so you have one result per item in the batch. Since the batch size is not usually fixed the shape remains `?`. Either collapse it to a single number with reduce_mean or if it make sense to you to have one per example specify the shape with `tf.reshape`. Tensorflow needs to know how many variables it has.

Answer (score 0):

Many things are unclear to me.

Why do you "break" the graph:

```
sample_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
r, p = fit_mme(sample_data) # pre-calculation

# The important part: make `r` trainable
r_var = tf.Variable(r, dtype=tf.float32, name="r")
```

r is already a Tensor that can be updated and thus you don't need to feed its value into a Variable. Especially if you don't want to make any numpy processing on it.

However, if you want to really do this you can do something like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

r, p = fit_mme(x) # pre-calculation
r_var = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.shape(r)), dtype=tf.float32, validate_shape=False, name="r_var")

r_assign_op = tf.assign(r_var, r)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #print (sess.run(r_var, feed_dict={x: [[3.4, 4.6], [5.4, 6.8]]}))
    print ("r_var before assign: %s" % sess.run(r_var))

    r_var_t, _ = sess.run([r_var, r_assign_op], feed_dict={x: [[3.4, 4.6], [5.4, 6.8]]})
    print ("r_var after assign: %s" % r_var_t)
```

Comment: "r is already a Tensor that can be updated"
No, it isn't. This is my problem.
`fit_mme` calculates `r` from `sample data`.
<br>
This is like the closed-form solution of a linear regression vs. optimizing it iteratively. I'd like to do both: first initialize with closed-form, then optimize it iteratively